# Estimating error in perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, error-analysis

Is there a simple way to estimate the error in the eigenvalues when approximating a hamiltonian by its $n^{th}$ order perturbation expansion?

Comment: Calculate the $n+1$st term? I have no idea if this problem has nice solution in this case.

Comment: you can get an estimate by the calculations of the Lamb shift with respect to the Schrodinger soluition  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/lamb.html , or the fine structure http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydfin.html

Comment: Yes, I thought the $n+1st$ term would be a good answer too at first, but then I noticed that there are some pathological cases where every even-order correction is zero, while the odd ones are not. I would like to have a strict upper bound to the error that would be guaranteed to hold, even in bad cases like this. As for the lamb shift, this seems to be specific for atomic physics and spin-degeneracy breaking, I don't see how this would apply to a $N-$dimensional arbitrary Hamiltonian.